# Laravel 5.2 BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 107: Method [save] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I can't figure out why am I getting this error.

Controller: SectionHeaderController

```
<?php

namespace SimpleCms\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\SectionHeader;


class SectionHeaderController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $header = new SectionHeader();
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png|max:1024|dimensions:max_width=300,max_height=100',
            'heading' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);
        $header->title = $request->title;
        $header->heading = $request->description;
        $header->description = $request->description;

        if($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = Input::file('image');
            $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());

            $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $header->filePath = $name;
            $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
        }
        $header->save();
        return $this->create()->with('success', 'Done!');
    }
}
```

Model: SectionHeader

```
<?php

namespace SimpleCms;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SectionHeader extends Model {

    protected $table = 'sectionheader';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'heading',
        'image'
    ];
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/home/store', 'SectionHeaderController@store' );
```

I don't know what is wrong nor how to fix this.
This error appears once I hit form submit which points to this `SectionHeaderController@store`
Any idea?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I changed per suggestions and I get new error

> FatalErrorException in SectionHeaderController.php line 34: Class
>   'App\SectionHeader' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code has very problem ...

i suggest use artisan commands for generate models and controller in future ...

in your model, namespace is not `App\SectionHeader` because of that you get this exception :  `get Class 'App\SectionHeader' not found`

change your model namespace to `App\SectionHeader`

in your controller, you create controller instead model :

```
$header = new SectionHeaderController():
```

instead

```
$header = new SectionHeaders();
```

and finally in end of store action, i don't know why you do this :

```
return $this->create()->with('success', 'Done!');
```

you should redirect to some route and set flash message or render a view with success message ...

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I will change that last part no worries but I can figure out why am I getting this error

Comment: change your model namespace to `App\SectionHeader` ... your namespace is : SimpleCms ... @Morpheus

Answer (score 1):

Can you change

> $header = new SectionHeaderController():

To

> $header = new SectionHeaders();

Comment: Awesome but I now get Class 'App\SectionHeader' not found

Comment: Sorry I see it but the problem is while I was waiting for an answer I deleted everything and named it like this `controller: SectionHeaderController`, model `SectionHeader` and I get that error after I changed what you wrote... So basically it is the same....

Comment: Can you try by rename model filename and its class as before SectionHeaders and in SectionHeaderController as well.